# How to git last tag value for git log pretty format?

Tags: git

I'm trying to generate some release notes using the following:

> git log --pretty=format:%s my-project-1.2..HEAD

However, how can I reuse something similar to this generically after each new rev instead of specifying the last known good rev (everytime) to work from (one down from head)?

i.e

> git log --pretty=format:%s [somehow get my-project-last-rev so I don't have to specify]..HEAD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git describe --abbrev=0 --tags` should give you the lastest tag "under" your current branch, so you could just use back-ticks to execute it inline:

```
git log --pretty=format:%s `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags`..HEAD
```